# Flex 3 compatibility mode

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flash-builder

I am working on a upgrade project where I am migrating from Flex 3 to Flex 4.

I want to ask about the difference between 'Flex 4' and 'Flex 4 with Flex 3 compatibility mode'. What are the pros and cons associated with them?

Is it better to do a full migration or a migration with compatibility mode?

Comment: I was pretty sure the only thing the Flash Builder "compatibility mode" checkbox does is use the Halo theme instead of the Spark theme; but don't quote me on that.  It appears the "wiki" article on this feature that a lot of places link to is no longer available; but there is some docs here which mention it casually: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashbuilder/using/WSe4e4b720da9dedb524b8220812e5611f28f-7fff.html#WSe4e4b720da9dedb524b8220812e5611f28f-7ff6

Comment: I voted to reopen as I don't understand why this question would be off-topic.  It seems like a solid question after @ben did some editing on the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was pretty sure the only thing the Flash Builder "compatibility mode" checkbox does is use the Halo theme instead of the Spark theme

It's not only relative to the Halo theme but it regards all the Flex 4 features, style enhancement, per module singletons, spark features and so on, all these things are disabled in compatility mode, basicly, you run under Flex 3 features only.

> I want to ask about the difference between 'Flex 4' and 'Flex 4 with Flex 3 compatibility mode'. What are the pros and cons associated with them?
>
> Is it better to do a full migration or a migration with compatibility mode?

That really relies on performances, staying in Flex 3 will give you the best performances, in compatibility mode, you'll have much more better perfs than in Flex 4 but a bit less than in Flex 3, you'll also benefit of fixes, in Flex 4, you'll loose perfs, it's better to start a new app in Flex 4 rather than migrate one especialy if your app is complex.